# Python-Kivy:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'volume'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm building a MP3 Player in Python 3.4 using the Kivy framework, everything seems to be working except for the volume control slider.

Whenever I click the volume button it gives me back: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'volume'`. I think it's because the sound is set to None. I'm still a newbie with Python and Kivy in general so I'm trying to learn from my mistakes, the code could be hard coded and I'm sorry for that, I accept any constructive criticism.

The code is a bit long so I'll provide only the part I'm having trouble with. I posted the entire code on pastebin, the link is below.

```
class MP3Win(BoxLayout):

   sound = None
   paused = False
   paused_position = 0

   def slider_vol(self):

    """slider volume to increase or decrease the volume
    of the sound manually with a popup box containing a
    a slider, however, if I don't put it under the 'if self.sound:'
    it keep giving me an attribute error NoneType has no attribute volume
    and it bother me because I cant open the volume slider
    unless there is a song playing."""

    slider = Slider(orientation='horizontal',min=0,max=1,value=self.sound.volume)
    popup = Popup(title='Speakers(Volume)',
                content=slider,
                size_hint=(None,None),size=(400,100),
                separator_height=1)
    popup.open()
    self.sound.bind(volume=slider.setter('value'))
    slider.bind(value=self.sound.setter('volume'))

    if self.sound.volume == 0:
        self.ids['vol_btn'].background_normal = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-muted'
        self.ids['vol_btn'].background_down = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-muted'
    elif self.sound.volume <= 0.3:
        self.ids['vol_btn'].background_normal = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-low'
        self.ids['vol_btn'].background_down = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-low'
    elif self.sound.volume <= 0.5:
        self.ids['vol_btn'].background_normal = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-medium'
        self.ids['vol_btn'].background_down = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-medium'
    elif self.sound.volume >= 0.7:
        self.ids['vol_btn'].background_normal = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'
        self.ids['vol_btn'].background_down = 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'

class MP3Player(App):
   def build(self):
       return MP3Win()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   MP3Player().run()
```

[Full code](http://pastebin.com/RAFck7r5)

Tl;Dr: Why does the volume slider throw `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'volume'` even though the rest of the code works fine? It's driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Couldn't find a fix yet I've been trying the past hours but I couldn't get over it still sadly, still waiting for an answer if possible and thanks again to Wander and Padraic!

EDIT #2: Still going crazy about it, without getting anywhere so far I'm still leaving this open if someone can help me out. Thanks so much!

Comment: You set the value of `self.sound` in the `load_file` method - could it be that `slider_vol` is called before `load_file` is called? If so, `self.sound` will still be `None`.

Comment: You need to have a song playing or self.sound is still None

Comment: A quick fix is to add   `if self.sound:` and indent all the code in `slider_vol` inside the if, but ideally you need to change the order

Comment: @Wander Nauta: I actually tried to disable `self.sound = SoundLoader.load(path)` but it still won't work, what I noticed is, if I put the whole code of `slider_vol` under an `if self.sound:` the slider volume will work but only after I selected a certain sound from the `file dialog`  @Padraic: Yes exactly what you said, that way it works even though I'd like to have full control of it even before I select a sound

Comment: @Ultima, that is because you never define it until you select a song

Comment: The gui is also going to freeze when you select a song

Comment: @Padraic, I didn't notice the freezing, well actually it doesnt freeze for me I don't know why, what I actually don't get is should I define `volume`? that's where I'm having headaches with, I do agree I should be changing order indeed

Comment: all the issues reside slider_vol, you can tackle it a few ways but I don't have time now, if you don't get an answer I will throw something together later

Comment: That would be a life safer! take your time and thanks alot for helping me out this much already :) in the meantime I'll be trying to do something by myself, if I happen to fix it I will edit my post so you know of any progress

Comment: I edited my thread as I couldn't fix it yet and still looking for it, thanks alot both of you!